# Creating static dropdownlist in Lightning

Tags: lightning-design-system

I am new to Lightning and was going through the documentation to create dropdown list . But mostly I am getting examples of Menu which I don't want.

My requirement is to create a dropdown with Label = Moth and the options would be 12 months .

```
<ui:inputSelect multiple="false">
<ui:inputSelectOption text="January" value="true"/>
<ui:inputSelectOption text="February"/>
<ui:inputSelectOption text="March"/>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

I was searching for the class name , but none has worked so far .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : Put your relevant Label and values.

```
<div class="label-box">
     <label>Year</label>
        <select tabindex="-1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                <optgroup label="Year">
                  <option value="" style="display: none;">Select</option>
                  <option value="2015">2014</option>
                  <option value="2015">2015</option>
                  <option value="2016">2016</option>
                  <option value="2015">2017</option>
                 </optgroup>
         </select>
     </div>
```